# Copy mdf file and use it in run time

Tags: sql, file, insert, mdf

After I copy mdf file (and his log file) I tries to Insert data.
I receive the following message:

"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file [fileName].mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

When I copied the file manual everything worked normally. 
Is it correct the order File.Copy leaves the file engaged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a connection open to the mdf file when you copy it.  This might be related to there being only one lock file for the two copies.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much more simple. 
I forgot to close the file

```
fileStream.Close();
```